# How can i write a csv file to an excel sheet using openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, openpyxl, xlwings

I am having some trouble writing an csv to an excel workbook. I have tried a series of options but i think openpyxl migth do job... however i cannot find a way to do this.

e.g.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl
import csv
#ceate workbook
wb = openpyxl.Workbook() 
TOP3 = wb.sheetnames
wb.create_sheet(title='metrics')
wb.save(filename='Test.xlsx')
sheet = wb["TOP3"]
#write an existing csv to the sheet above: 

    with open('metrics.csv', 'r') as f:  
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            for i in range(0,len(row)):
                sheet[f"""A{i}"""] = row
```

above does not work! How can I read a csv file into an excel workbook? I would like to automate this. I basically want to import my metrics csv into the metrics tab of my workbook

Comment: `for row in reader: sheet.append(row)`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('metrics.csv')
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='metrics', index=False)
```

Comment: This works but i am trying to output multiple csvs to the same excel workbook and that only lets me output one csv to one workbook